# HELP: MS Virtual Disk Service to Access Volumes and Discs on Local Machine

Tags: windows, visual-c++

here it is my code through which I am successfully initialize the VDS service and get the Packs but When I call QueryVolumes on IVdsPack Object, I am able to get IEnumVdsObjects but unable to get IUnknown* array through IEnumVdsObject::Next method, it reutrns S_FALSE with IUnkown* = NULL. So this IUnknown* cant be used to QueryInterface for IVdsVolume

Below is my code

```
    HRESULT hResult;
IVdsService* pService = NULL;
IVdsServiceLoader *pLoader = NULL;

//Launch the VDS Service
hResult = CoInitialize(NULL);
if( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
{
    hResult = CoCreateInstance( 
                                CLSID_VdsLoader,
                                NULL,
                                CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                                IID_IVdsServiceLoader,
                                (void**) &pLoader
                                );

    //if succeeded load VDS on local machine
    if( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
        pLoader->LoadService(NULL, &pService);

    //Done with Loader now release VDS Loader interface
    _SafeRelease(pLoader);

    if( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
    {
        hResult = pService->WaitForServiceReady();
        if ( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
        {
            AfxMessageBox(L"VDS Service Loaded");
            IEnumVdsObject* pEnumVdsObject = NULL;
            hResult = pService->QueryProviders(VDS_QUERY_SOFTWARE_PROVIDERS, &pEnumVdsObject);

            IUnknown* ppObjUnk ;
            IVdsSwProvider* pVdsSwProvider = NULL;
            IVdsPack* pVdsPack = NULL;
            IVdsVolume* pVdsVolume = NULL;
            ULONG ulFetched = 0;

            hResult = E_INVALIDARG;
            while(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
            {
                hResult = pEnumVdsObject->Next(1, &ppObjUnk, &ulFetched);
                hResult = ppObjUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IVdsSwProvider, (void**)&pVdsSwProvider);
                if(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                    _SafeRelease(ppObjUnk);
            }
            _SafeRelease(pEnumVdsObject);
            _SafeRelease(ppObjUnk);

            hResult = pVdsSwProvider->QueryPacks(&pEnumVdsObject);

            hResult = E_INVALIDARG;
            while(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
            {
                hResult = pEnumVdsObject->Next(1, &ppObjUnk, &ulFetched);
                hResult = ppObjUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IVdsPack, (void**)&pVdsPack);
                if(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                    _SafeRelease(ppObjUnk);
            }

            _SafeRelease(pEnumVdsObject);
            _SafeRelease(ppObjUnk);

            hResult = pVdsPack->QueryVolumes(&pEnumVdsObject);
            pEnumVdsObject->Reset();

            hResult = E_INVALIDARG;
            ulFetched = 0;
            BOOL bDone = FALSE;
            while(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
            {
                hResult = pEnumVdsObject->Next(1, &ppObjUnk, &ulFetched);
                //hResult = ppObjUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IVdsVolume, (void**)&pVdsVolume);
                if(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                    _SafeRelease(ppObjUnk);
            }
            _SafeRelease(pEnumVdsObject);
            _SafeRelease(ppObjUnk);
            _SafeRelease(pVdsPack);
            _SafeRelease(pVdsSwProvider);

//              hResult = pVdsVolume->AddAccessPath(TEXT("G:\\"));
            if(SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                AfxMessageBox(L"Add Access Path Successfully");
            else
                AfxMessageBox(L"Unable to Add access path");

            //UUID of IVdsVolumeMF {EE2D5DED-6236-4169-931D-B9778CE03DC6}
            static const GUID GUID_IVdsVolumeMF = {0xEE2D5DED, 0x6236, 4169,{0x93, 0x1D, 0xB9, 0x77, 0x8C, 0xE0, 0x3D, 0XC6} };

            hResult = pService->GetObject(GUID_IVdsVolumeMF, VDS_OT_VOLUME, &ppObjUnk);
            if(hResult == VDS_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND)
                AfxMessageBox(L"Object Not found");
            if(hResult == VDS_E_INITIALIZED_FAILED)
                AfxMessageBox(L"Initialization failed");
//              pVdsVolume = reinterpret_cast<IVdsVolumeMF*>(ppObjUnk);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hResult))
            {
//                  hResult = pVdsVolume->AddAccessPath(TEXT("G:\\"));

                if(SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                {
                    IVdsAsync* ppVdsSync;
                    AfxMessageBox(L"Formatting is about to Start......");
//                      hResult = pVdsVolume->Format(VDS_FST_UDF, TEXT("UDF_FORMAT_TEST"), 2048, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, &ppVdsSync);

                    if(SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                        AfxMessageBox(L"Formatting Started.......");
                    else
                    AfxMessageBox(L"Formatting Failed");
                }
                else
                    AfxMessageBox(L"Unable to Add Access Path");
            }
            _SafeRelease(pVdsVolume);
        }

        else
        {
            AfxMessageBox(L"VDS Service Cannot be Loaded");
        }
    }
}
_SafeRelease(pService);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your other loops inside your while loop that enumerates your IVdsSwProviders.

I modified your code for my own purpose.  You have to be careful because I threw it together for a test and therefore didn't care about memory leaks and freeing COM objects.  I also have a lot of debug prints in there too:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "initguid.h"
#include <vds.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "ole32.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "rpcrt4.lib" )

#define _SafeRelease(x) {if (NULL != x) { x->Release(); x = NULL; } }


void EnumerateDisks(IVdsPack* pPack)
{
    HRESULT hResult;
    ULONG ulFetched = 0;
    IUnknown* ppObjUnk ;
    IEnumVdsObject* pEnumVdsObject = NULL;  
    IVdsDisk* pVdsDisk = NULL;
    IVdsDisk2* pVdsDisk2 = NULL;
    IVdsAdvancedDisk* pVdsAdvancedDisk = NULL;

    if (pPack == 0)
        return;

    hResult = pPack->QueryDisks(&pEnumVdsObject);

    if (pEnumVdsObject == 0)
        return;

    while( true)
    {
        if (!pEnumVdsObject)
            break;

        hResult = pEnumVdsObject->Next(1, &ppObjUnk, &ulFetched);
        if (ulFetched == 0) break;

        hResult = ppObjUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IVdsDisk, (void**)&pVdsDisk);

        VDS_DISK_PROP diskProp;
        pVdsDisk->GetProperties(&diskProp);

        printf("----------------------------------------\n");
        wprintf(L"disk: %d\n", diskProp.status);
        wprintf(L"disk: %s\n", diskProp.pwszAdaptorName);
        wprintf(L"disk: %s\n", diskProp.pwszDevicePath);
        wprintf(L"disk: %s\n", diskProp.pwszFriendlyName);
        wprintf(L"disk: %s\n", diskProp.pwszName);
        wprintf(L"disk: %d\n", diskProp.dwDeviceType);
        wprintf(L"disk: %d\n", diskProp.dwMediaType);
        wprintf(L"disk: %d\n", diskProp.dwSignature);
        wprintf(L"disk: %d\n", diskProp.PartitionStyle);
        wprintf(L"disk: %d\n", diskProp.ReserveMode);
        wprintf(L"disk: %d\n", diskProp.ulFlags);

        VDS_PARTITION_PROP * pPropArray = NULL;
        LONG pNumberOfPartitions = 0;

        hResult = ppObjUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IVdsAdvancedDisk, (void**)&pVdsAdvancedDisk);        
        pVdsAdvancedDisk->QueryPartitions(&pPropArray, &pNumberOfPartitions);

        VDS_PARTITION_PROP * tmp = pPropArray;
        for (int i = 0; i < pNumberOfPartitions; ++i)
        {
            printf("Number: %d\n", tmp->ulPartitionNumber);
            printf("Style : %d\n", tmp->PartitionStyle);
            printf("Flags : %d\n", tmp->ulFlags);
            printf("Offset: %ull\n", tmp->ullOffset);
            printf("Size: %ull\n", tmp->ullSize);
            printf("MBR type: %d\n", tmp->Mbr.partitionType);
            printf("MBR type: %d\n", tmp->Mbr.bootIndicator);
            printf("MBR type: %d\n", tmp->Mbr.recognizedPartition);
            printf("MBR type: %d\n", tmp->Mbr.hiddenSectors);

            ++tmp;
        }
        CoTaskMemFree(pPropArray);
    }
}

void EnumerateVolumes(IVdsPack* pPack)
{
    HRESULT hResult;
    ULONG ulFetched = 0;
    IUnknown* ppObjUnk ;
    IEnumVdsObject* pEnumVdsObject = NULL;  
    IVdsVolume* pVdsVolume = NULL;

    if (pPack == 0)
        return;

    hResult = pPack->QueryVolumes(&pEnumVdsObject);

    if (pEnumVdsObject == 0)
        return;

    while( true)
    {
        hResult = pEnumVdsObject->Next(1, &ppObjUnk, &ulFetched);
        if (ulFetched == 0) break;

        hResult = ppObjUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IVdsVolume, (void**)&pVdsVolume);
        VDS_VOLUME_PROP volProp;
        pVdsVolume->GetProperties(&volProp);
        printf("Vol name  : %S\n", volProp.pwszName);
        printf("Vol health: %d\n", volProp.health);
    }
}

void EnumeratePacks(IVdsSwProvider* pProvider)
{
    HRESULT hResult;
    ULONG ulFetched = 0;
    IUnknown* ppObjUnk ;
    IEnumVdsObject* pEnumVdsObject = NULL;  
    IVdsPack* pVdsPack = NULL;

    if (pProvider == 0)
        return;

    hResult = pProvider->QueryPacks(&pEnumVdsObject);

    if (pEnumVdsObject == 0)
        return;

    while( true)
    {
        hResult = pEnumVdsObject->Next(1, &ppObjUnk, &ulFetched);
        if (ulFetched == 0) break;

        hResult = ppObjUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IVdsPack, (void**)&pVdsPack);
        VDS_PACK_PROP packProp;
        pVdsPack->GetProperties(&packProp);
        if (packProp.status == VDS_PS_ONLINE) {
            printf("Pack name  : %S\n", packProp.pwszName);
            printf("Pack status: %d\n", packProp.status);
            printf("Pack flags : %d\n", packProp.ulFlags);
            EnumerateDisks(pVdsPack);
            EnumerateVolumes(pVdsPack);
        }
    }
}


void EnumerateSoftwareProviders(IVdsService* pService)
{
    HRESULT hResult;
    ULONG ulFetched = 0;
    IUnknown* ppObjUnk ;
    IEnumVdsObject* pEnumVdsObject = NULL;
    IVdsSwProvider* pVdsSwProvider = NULL;

    hResult = pService->QueryProviders(VDS_QUERY_SOFTWARE_PROVIDERS, &pEnumVdsObject);
    while( true)
    {
        hResult = pEnumVdsObject->Next(1, &ppObjUnk, &ulFetched);
        if (ulFetched == 0) break;

        hResult = ppObjUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IVdsSwProvider,(void**)&pVdsSwProvider);
        EnumeratePacks(pVdsSwProvider);
    }
}


int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    HRESULT hResult;
    IVdsService* pService = NULL;
    IVdsServiceLoader *pLoader = NULL;
    //Launch the VDS Service
    hResult = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    // Initialize COM security
    CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,       // Allow *all* VSS writers to communicate back!
        -1,        // Default COM authentication service
        NULL,       // Default COM authorization service
        NULL,       // reserved parameter
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, // Strongest COM authentication level
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // Minimal impersonation abilities 
        NULL,       // Default COM authentication settings
        EOAC_NONE,      // No special options
        NULL       // Reserved parameter
        );

    if( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
    {
        hResult = CoCreateInstance( 
            CLSID_VdsLoader,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
            IID_IVdsServiceLoader,
            (void**) &pLoader
            );

        //if succeeded load VDS on local machine
        if( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
            pLoader->LoadService(NULL, &pService);
        //Done with Loader now release VDS Loader interface
        _SafeRelease(pLoader);

        if( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
        {
            hResult = pService->WaitForServiceReady();
            if ( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
            {
                EnumerateSoftwareProviders(pService);
                return 0;       
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the variable type might be "unsigned long long" but the format for the printf should be "llu" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx